# Using Group in LINQ Query

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the LINQ to CRM provider.

I am querying the information then I am using LINQ to query the LINQ to CRM query so I can use GroupBy, since the LINQ to CRM provider does not support it. This is what I have so far.

```
var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on 
        ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"] into opp
    from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") 
            ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
        CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") 
            ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
        OwnerId = !r.Contains("ownerid") 
            ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id.ToString(),
        OwnerName = !r.Contains("ownerid") 
            ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Name.ToString(),
        Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") 
            ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
        ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") 
            ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
        // ...
        // other properties  
    });

var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
                  group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
                  select new
                  {
                      OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
                  });
```

But I also want to be able to query the other variables that are in `linqQuery` from `linqQuery2`.

So I would want something like:

```
var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
                  group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
                  select new
                  {
                      OwnerName = myGroup.OwnerName,
                      OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
                  });
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the OwnerNames will be identical for all the items in the group then you could do something like:

```
var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
    group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
    select new
    {
        OwnerName = myGroup.First().OwnerName,
        OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
    });
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use the first item multiple times, I'd suggest you use the 'let' operator:

```
var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
                    group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
                    let first = myGroup.First()
                    select new
                    {
                        OwnerName = first.OwnerName,
                        OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks That seemed to work. If I want to get more variables from the first query say "Notes" can I keep using the First()?

Comment: You certainly can, although each time you call First() or Count() you are causing another evaluation of the delayed linq query. See edit for solution to this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it searches all of them in a group for a certain value instead of just the first. So for example. It counts all the LeadShare variables with a value of 100000000. So if I have 10 owners with the same id and 5 of them have a LeadShare value of 100000000 then it give a count of 5. Right now it seems to just look for the first one and if it doesnt match it ignores the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Probably best to post a new question for this one. I actually haven't spent a heap of time with LINQ and CRM2011 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
                          group f by f.OwnerName
                          into myGroup
                          select new
                                     {
                                         OwnerName = myGroup.Key,
                                         OwnerCount = myGroup.Count()
                                     });
```

Alternately:

```
        var linqQuery2 = linqQuery.ToList()
            .GroupBy(f => f.OwnerName)
            .Select(myGroup => new
                                {
                                    OwnerName = myGroup.Key,
                                    OwnerCount = myGroup.Count()
                                });
```

Comment: In using this method, you'd want to make sure that multiple owners don't have the same name. Otherwise, your grouping won't be correct.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't let me select the other variables from linqQuery though.