# Counting other relations for every person that is connected to this particular company

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using QueryExpression to retrieve all connections for a company in MSCRM 2016.

It gives me record2roleid like "employee", "managing director" or "board member"

But I want to count all other relations that this person would maybe have to some other companies like if a board member is sitting in 3 companies the sub-join would give me count:3

This is what I have now:

```
//guid for the company Cola Cola Inc, for example
guid accountid = "8e7fbd04-d12a-443a-998b-e0ea5801f315"            

//first we retrieve every connection for this company
var query = new QueryExpression("connection")
                {
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("connectionid", "record2id", "record2roleid")
                };

//all connections that are connected to Coca Cola Inc
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("record1id", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountid));
//just the active ones
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0));

//link to contact for more detailed information about the person
query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("connection", "contact", "record2id", "contactid", joinOperator: JoinOperator.LeftOuter)
{
EntityAlias = "contact",
Columns = new ColumnSet("fullname", "address1_name", "regno")

//count connections for this individual, by joining connection from contact and count all relations that contact has to other companies

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Now you can loop through the contacts you retrieve with this query to get their connections to Accounts other than this Account and count them after retrieval.

Or, you could do a [FetchXML aggregate with group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#groupby) to get counts directly.

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='opportunity'> 
       <attribute name='name' alias='opportunity_count' aggregate='countcolumn' /> 
       <attribute name='ownerid' alias='ownerid' groupby='true' /> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>";
```

Or, you could theoretically get something going with [LINQ], as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642365/using-group-in-linq-query) shows:

```
var linqQuery2 = (from f in linqQuery.ToList()
    group f by f.OwnerId into myGroup
    select new
    {
        OwnerName = myGroup.First().OwnerName,
        OrderCount = myGroup.Count()
    });
```